# Using Google App Engine & Spring Boot, How to override or increase jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize & responseHeaderSize?

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, http-headers, jetty

My application is using Google App Engine(GAE) and Spring boot (v2.0.1). GAE runs the app with Jetty 9.3, where the default Request and Response Header Size are set to **8192**. 
I need to increase these values since I have a technical requirement to handle large header.

Could you guys help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not running an embedded Jetty, you should be able to use the env variables as stated in Google's documentation : 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-jetty9

> To set environment variables, use the env_variables key in the
>   app.yaml file.
>
> JETTY_PROPERTIES: Comma separated list of name=value pairs appended to $JETTY_ARGS

And also used here on their docker image :
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/jetty-runtime

> ```
>  docker run -it --rm -e JETTY_PROPERTIES=jetty.http.idleTimeout=10000
>  launcher.gcr.io/google/jetty
> ```

The needed properties, supposedly :

```
JETTY_PROPERTIES=jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize=X,jetty.httpConfig.responseHeaderSize=X
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback; I understand that your solution required to have Flexible environment, correct ? I tried different way to implement your solution and still stuck. Could you provide a sample ?